# Python: Why isn't my google webscraping code using beautifulsoup returning the search results?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a python script to show me the links to the top 5 results in google for a given search query.

I'm using beautiful soup, and after inspecting the html for google, I found that the search result links can be found inside the tags 'div class="r"' and 'a href'.

```
import bs4, requests

mySearch=input()
address='http://www.google.com/search?q='+mySearch
googleRes=requests.get(address)

googleSoup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(googleRes.text)
linkBlocks=googleSoup.select('div.r a')
```

However, the list, linkBlocks is empty, instead of being filled with the search result links. How do I get the search result links into the linkBlocks list.

Comment: It is not a very straight forward thing to scrape google. It is very well aware when it is used by a user or a bot. If you don't have some headers set or spam it with requests, it will probably not return any results.

Answer (score 2):

Use `User-Agent`

```
import bs4, requests
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
mySearch="beautifulsoup"
address='http://www.google.com/search?q='+mySearch
googleRes=requests.get(address,headers=headers)
googleSoup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(googleRes.text,'html.parser')
linkBlocks=googleSoup.select('div.r a')
print(linkBlocks)
```

Comment: @Neji Yang to get your User-Agent as KunduK suggested do a quick Google search with "my user agent" and you get a similar information related to your browser.